# Ruby Mechanize, fill dynamic Form / Send JSON (Airbnb calendar)

Tags: ruby, json, nokogiri, mechanize

### My goal

I try to update my airbnb calendar using Ruby. For example, here is a URL of a calendar : `https://www.airbnb.com/manage-listing/ROOM_ID/calendar`

### The issue

If you already use Airbnb, to update your calendar, you have to click on the start date then the end date and **after that, a form pop-up**.
So, when I use Mechanize to get the page content, this form is not loaded and doesn't appears (even the calendar is load dynamically, not able to simulate click too), impossible to use basic Mechanize form filling...

### What I did so far

I tried to use the developer tools from Chrome to check the Network. When I update my calendar using Chrome, there is one JSON PUT at `https://www.airbnb.com/api/v2/calendars/ROOM_ID/START_DATE/END_DATE?_format=host_calendar&t=1427377357561&key=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20` with some JSON data such as days, availability, price...

My first solution was to tried to reproduce this JSON call with this code :

```
data = {  "event_name" => "calendar",
          "event_data" => { "page_uri" => "/manage-listing/ROOM_ID/calendar",
                            "controller" => "rooms",
                            "action" => "manage_listing",
                            "hosting_id" => ROOM_ID,
                            "start_date" => "2015-03-26",
                            "end_date" => "2015-03-29",
                            "available" => true,
                            "native_price" => 111,
                            "native_currency" => "EUR"
                          }
        }

page = agent.post 'https://www.airbnb.com/api/v2/calendars/ROOM_ID/2015-03-26/2015-03-29?_format=host_calendar&t=1427374574309&key=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20', data.to_json, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
```

But I get a 404 response :

```
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError (404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for https://www.airbnb.com/api/v2/calendars/ROOM_ID/2015-03-26/2015-03-29?_format=host_calendar&t=1427374574309&key=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20 -- unhandled response)
```

---

*Do you have any suggestions to either send the form even if it is not on the page content, or POST the request with JSON ?*

Thanks for your help

---

Here is the complete JSON call from Chrome :

**General**

```
Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xx:xx
Request URL:https://www.airbnb.com/api/v2/calendars/ROOM_ID/2015-03-26/2015-03-29?_format=host_calendar&t=1427379998507&key=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20&currency=EUR&locale=fr-CA
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK
```

**Response Headers**

```
cache-control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
connection:keep-alive
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:236
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
date:Thu, 26 Mar 2015 14:26:46 GMT
etag:W/"10845765865e36a6ccb1541bbda1c2a7"
server:nginx/1.7.7
status:200 OK
status:200 OK
strict-transport-security:max-age=10886400; includeSubdomains
vary:Accept-Encoding
version:HTTP/1.1
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-hi-human:The Production Infrastructure team added this header. Come work with us! Email kevin.rice+hiring@airbnb.com
x-ua-compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

**Request Headers**

```
:host:www.airbnb.com
:method:PUT
:path:/api/v2/calendars/ROOM_ID/2015-03-26/2015-03-29?_format=host_calendar&t=1427379998507&key=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20&currency=EUR&locale=fr-CA
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
accept-language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
content-length:59
content-type:application/json
cookie:__ssid=4166c81a-49bd-4826-ac44-08307c5700ca; _csrf_token=V4%24.airbnb.ca%24CL1nNdfYkF0%24ulPyJJJWr1h6CvuBMf32YcXtnZssDud3_CqBQoqXOU0%3D; li=1; roles=0; _airbed_session_id=dfa72c17e6d014f9fd0b9705d097e5d8; flags=4027711488; EPISODES=s=1427377914349&r=https%3A%2F%2Ffr.airbnb.ca%2Fmanage-listing%2F5780104%2Fcalendar; _ga=GA1.2.1981489078.1427272843; fbs=not_authorized; _pt=1--WyJjZmYxZmE4N2RhOTU4NGNhYzhhN2M5YTIyNzkyMDliMDI0YTk1YWEzIl0%3D--2890e7d8df5181677516659fbdc4761e6de82a61; bev=1427272835_bw8KI59ELTQAsMt3; _user_attributes=%7B%22curr%22%3A%22EUR%22%2C%22guest_exchange%22%3A0.9134%2C%22id%22%3A29905162%2C%22hash_user_id%22%3A%22cff1fa87da9584cac8a7c9a2279209b024a95aa3%22%2C%22eid%22%3A%22FBPqvskr4MN1Rnpqf-oY-lG7-VNdCJVSYwUMUtm6YyOXzEpbRvmU9FWTxKNdf0UA%22%2C%22num_msg%22%3A0%2C%22num_h%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22St%C3%A9phane%22%2C%22is_admin%22%3Afalse%2C%22can_access_photography%22%3Afalse%7D
origin:https://www.airbnb.com
referer:https://www.airbnb.com/manage-listing/ROOM_ID/calendar
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
x-csrf-token:V4$.airbnb.ca$CL1nNdfYkF0$ulPyJJJWr1h6CvuBMf32YcXtnZssDud3_CqBQoqXOU0=
x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Query String Parameters**

```
_format:host_calendar
t:1427379998507
key:d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20
currency:EUR
locale:fr-CA
```

**Request Payload**

```
{availability: "available", daily_price: "999", notes: ""}
availability: "available"
daily_price: "999"
notes: ""
```

Comment: It's ridiculous that they don't have an API. Have you asked them about that?

Comment: To my knowledge, sadly, there is no API for Airbnb...

Comment: Put and post are not the same thing.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes I tried both PUT and POST without success yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded to update the calendar of my room I used a JSON PUT request. Here is what I did.

The data looks like :

```
data = {  "availability" => availability,
          "daily_price" => price, 
          "notes" => note
       }.to_json
```

Retrieve the cookie :

```
cookie_csrf_token = ''
cookie_airbed_session_id = ''
agent.cookie_jar.each do |value|
  if value.to_s.include? "_csrf_token"
    cookie_csrf_token = value.to_s
  elsif value.to_s.include? "_airbed_session_id"
    cookie_airbed_session_id = value.to_s
  end
end
```

The headers :

```
headers = { 'X-CSRF-Token' => URI.unescape(cookie_csrf_token.scan(/=(.*)/).join(",")),
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Cookie' => "#{cookie_csrf_token}; #{cookie_airbed_session_id}"
          }
```

The only cookies you need is csrf_token and airbed_session_id which are related to each other. My mistake was to use the csrf_token from the login page... You can find these cookies in the cookie_jar variable from your Mechanize agent.

---

After that you will need to construct your URL. The URL has a particular parameter which is called "key". You can retrieve it in a meta tag (`id='_bootstrap-layout-init'`) from your calendar page. Do to that I used Nokogiri combined with some regex :

```
param_t = Time.now.to_i
noko.xpath("//meta[@id='_bootstrap-layout-init']/@content").each do |attr|
  param_key = attr.value[/key":"(.*?)"/, 1]
end
```

---

Now you are good to go to update your calendar :

```
url = "https://www.airbnb.com"
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

# Send the PUT request to update the calendar
res = http.start { |req|
  req.send_request('PUT', "/api/v2/calendars/#{room_id}/#{start_date}/#{end_date}?_format=host_calendar&t=#{param_t}&key=#{param_key}", data, headers)
}
```

Comment: I'm sending _airbed_session_id and _csfr_token tokens and get operations work. Unfortunatelly POST do not work unless I specify X-CSFR-TOKEN header. In that case POST still not work but instead of 401(without header) I'm getting redirected to home page. What value should header be, how to get it. What I'm doing wrong?